# `find_rtools` no longer in `devtools` package

Tags: r, devtools, rtools

I've (once again) run into problems with Rtools and package installation issues (Error 127). I've been through the various fixes that involve changing your path and running`devtools::find_rtools` to make sure you configured it correctly.

```
> packageVersion('devtools')
[1] ‘2.0.1’
> devtools::find_rtools()
Error: 'find_rtools' is not an exported object from 'namespace:devtools'
```

I just wanted to make sure other people have been experiencing the same issue. It seems from the [devtools github](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1909) that this is an unresolved problem. I've also been to the github pages for packages I'm failing to install, and there seems to be currently unaddressed issues related to Rtools (e.g. [feather](https://github.com/wesm/feather/issues/346) package).

Thanks SO community.

Comment: `find_rtools()` was not re-exported by devtools from pkgbuild, but now it should be: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/pull/1969 and https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/pull/1969/commits/1dc9fb91f41523f9fa5cd7c33fd87e3df20c56bf